# Different responses from browser and application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When I try to access a URL for my application,in Browser i am getting one response but when same URL is used in the application I am getting some other response. What do u think is the prob??

**Output in Browser:**

```
−
<Rowsets DateCreated="2011-08-25T02:56:24" EndDate="2011-08-25T02:55:59" StartDate="2011-08-25T01:55:59" Version="12.1.8 Build(20)">
−
<Rowset>
−
<Columns>
<Column Description="Role" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Role" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Role"/>
</Columns>
−
<Row>
<Role>Administrator</Role>
</Row>
−
<Row>
<Role>Everyone</Role>
</Row>
−
<Row>
<Role>QUALITY_REVIEWER</Role>
</Row>
−
<Row>
<Role>SAP_XMII_Developer</Role>
</Row>
−
<Row>
<Role>SAP_XMII_User</Role>
</Row>
</Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

**Output in Console/Application**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Rowsets DateCreated="2011-08-25T04:55:37" EndDate="2011-08-25T04:55:11" StartDate="2011-08-25T03:55:11" Version="12.1.8 Build(20)"> 
<FatalError>
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
</FatalError>
</Rowsets>
```

Answer (score 1):

What u get is an error message, not the requested data - see body of the response.

Check your calling routine

Comment: my calling routine is fine.. there is no prob with my calling routine. for other URLs its working fine only for 2 to 3 URLs.. also.. after constructing the URL in my application I printed that URL in console and I checked that URL in browser. it was same.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely some non-obvious differences between the browser request and the app request you are not seeing. If you are using Safari as your browser, try enabling the developer tools and turning on the web inspector. You can see the details of your browser request, any headers it is sending, etc. Your app may not be sending all the exact same things.

If you really want to compare the two requests in detail, use a tool to capture the HTTP traffic and display it. I use TuffCode's [HTTPScoop](http://www.tuffcode.com/) but there are lots of other ways to monitor traffic. With a tool like this, you can capture the request you make from your browser and the request you make from your app, and the compare them.